# rref matrix equations k2-2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question is about reduced row echelon form, Gauss-Jordan, inverting matrices, and solving systems of equations.

I try to solve a system of equations with matrices. I know what operations are allowed, but I just seem to arrive at the wrong conclusion 50 % of the times. So here are three problems, each with my calculation. My hope is to clarify if I:

- am making a careless misstake, and where those mistakes are (if so, I may have to do these problems in a slower pace)
- do not know the theory well enough (don't make the correct steps)
- use a bad or "not smart" way of attacking the problem. (for example, if I do *row1 + row2* when I shoul have taken *row1 - row3*).

[image: pb1]

Comment: The reduction should get you: $x = -69/41$, $y = 327/41$, $z = 6/41$. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You want to make it as easy for yourself as possible. For example, in the first step you have 1 as the leading entry in the first row, so use this to get rid of the 10 and 7 below it by subtracting 10 lots of the first row from the second, and 7 lots of the first row from the first row. Then your first column will just be $(1, 0, 0)^T$.

Then you already have part of your matrix in rref. Continue in this way for the other rows - aim to eliminate any entries above and below the leading entry of the next row and then divide through to make the entry 1.